# Will grub overwrite EasyBCD entry if I already have Windows 7 and Windows XP installed?

Tags: grub2, dual-boot, easybcd

Installing Ubuntu on EEE PC which already has Windows 7 and Windows XP in dual boot using Easy BCD

I have an ASUS EEE PC 1015PEM with Windows 7 starter and Windows XP in dual boot configuration on separate partitions.

Now I want to replace my Windows XP with Ubuntu 11. Earlier after installing XP on my system it failed to boot in Windows 7, which I restored easily using EasyBCD.

If I install Ubuntu 11 will I be able to boot my Windows 7 also? Will grub overwrite the EasyBCD entry for XP?

Answer (score 0):

By installing Ubuntu with the option "Install side by side with Windows 7" for a [**dual-boot installation**](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/WindowsDualBoot) you will **replace the MBR** and by this also your Easy BCD bootloader by Grub2.

Before you install Ubuntu you will have to **delete the partition that holds Windows XP** to make space for the Ubuntu OS. No need to format or partition at this point, the installer will do that for you later.

When your disk is fairly standard partitioned then **Grub2 will detect any exisiting Windows 7 installation**, and will offer a menu choice at boot to choose the OS you want to run. Thus, if you have a spare partition you may also install Ubuntu as triple-boot with Windows 7 and Windows XP.

In theory it is also possible to chainload Grub from Easy BCD but this is a rare installation type, and thus not really recommended.

In case your Windows Boot Record fails to start Windows 7 you may have to rebuild it with the help of a Windows repair or installation CD. Thenafter a reinstallation of Grub2 is needed for booting Ubuntu.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply.. that really helped me and now running  win 7 and ubuntu successfully on my eee pc...

Comment: @Sachin: glad you got it sorted out. Don't forget to `accept' the answer to get it from the list of unanswered questions.